# Unable to parse xml from response

Tags: php, xml, laravel, xml-parsing, simplexml

Hi I get this XML as response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Response>
  <Environment>PRODUCTION</Environment>
  <Method/>
  <ResponseCode>03</ResponseCode>
  <ResponseDescription>Invalid Merchant</ResponseDescription>
  <Fee>0.00</Fee>
</Response>
```

Can someone tell me how do I parse it?

That xml I get if print `$response->getBody()->getContents()`

I try with `simplexml_load_string($response->getBody())` and that gives me an error:

> simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : XML
>   declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Also try with `simplexml_load_string($response->getBody()->getContents())` like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response->getBody()->getContents()); if ($xml === false) { echo "Failed loading XML: "; foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) { echo "<br>", $error->message; } } else { print_r($xml); }
```

it returns me only `Failed loading XML: without any error`.

Also try with `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response->getBody());` and get this error: `String could not be parsed as XML`

Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: try to strip out the  `<?xml version="1.0"?>` before passing it to `simplexml_load_string`

Comment: Are there any white spaces before `<?xml version="1.0"?>` in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that there are no white spaces in front of the xml declaration, these should always be the first bytes of an xml string.

Try using [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to make sure this is so:

```
simplexml_load_string(trim($response->getBody()));
```

Comment: It helps! TNX a lot!